# "Bend mode" equivalent in Kicad 5

Tags: eaglecad, kicad

In the switching from Eagle to Kicad the first thing I was missing are the bend modes. In Eagle you can very quicky change weather you want to prefer a right turn or left on the fly via the "bend mode". Is there something like this in Kicad 5? I'm aware of the quite powerful drag feature, but I liked the bend mode quite a bit.

Comment: Have you tried the "/" key?  In KiCad it is called switch posture.

Comment: You can get thoses modes https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-a5oa9coweVco7vMM0iRM1MOKoVVUgG0 from route/interactive_router_settings menu I'm not sure it is the same function on eagle but it really helps.

Comment: @Seth you might enter your comment as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the posture of of a track in KiCad using the "/" by default.  The command is called "Switch Posture".  Note that this can be overridden by connecting to a pad, so if you lose the posture, click prior to the pad to lock the track in place before connecting.